# JAVA - Parse String date to long

Tags: android-studio, datetime, simpledateformat, iso8601

```
2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

I would like to get this String in ms(long)
I tried:

```
long res = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(createdAt).getTime();
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: *It doesn‘t work* is not an error description.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy. `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long res = Instant.parse("2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1704067200000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CTJ5jd)

Note that the modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### For any reason, if you want to use `SimpleDateFormat`:

Use the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

Check the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation to understand the difference between `Z` and `X`.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Good Answer, of course. I suggest adding a summary up top of simply `Instant.parse("2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toEpochMilli()`.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque for the valuable feedback as usual. However, everyone on SO knows that probably nobody else has perfected that art of putting the summary at the top as you do. Feel free to edit it whenever you have some time.